# Angular directive async data not binding?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, d3.js

This is the sample code i tried to implement my directive: [donut-chart.directive](https://github.com/vicapow/angular-d3-talk/blob/master/slides/demos/a-donut-chart-editor/donut-chart.directive.js)

I modified this controller js [(code)](https://github.com/vicapow/angular-d3-talk/blob/master/slides/demos/a-donut-chart-editor/app.js) to get data from web api using `$http.get`

But here not passing data into directive it is `undefined` in the isolate scope. Please give suitable solution for this.

Thank you

Comment: How does a question like this get 3 up-votes...  **How did you modify the controller.js code?**  And as @brianliu states below, you **must** handle the async nature of JavaScript.  You can't plot data you don't have yet.

Answer (score 1):

`$http.get` is async, if you `console.log('scope.data', scope.data);` in `donut-chart.directive` will be undefined because the promise is not yet resolved.

I suggest you can add data dependency to `$routeProvider` to make sure all the data is fetched before route change

```
.when('/edit', {
  controller: 'MainCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'edit.html',
  resolve: function() {
      // your $http get data and return promise in this function
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Brian Liu for the answer but i cannot use this option in my scenario

Comment: No worries, as long as you found the solution fits your project.